# can't serve public static file flask

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask

```
app = Flask(__name__,
            static_path='',
            static_url_path=None,
            static_folder='templates/assets',
            template_folder='templates',
            instance_path=None,
            instance_relative_config=False)
app.debug = False




@app.route("/", methods=['GET'])
def index():
    return render_template("index.html")

@app.route('/results/<path:filename>', methods=['GET'])
def serve_static(filename):
    root_dir = os.path.dirname(os.getcwd())
    #for windows too
    return app.send_static_file(os.path.join('results', filename).replace('\\','/'))
```

What do I do wrong?
http://127.0.0.1:5000/assets/result.csv
this gives me an error:

> Not Found The requested URL was not found on the server. If you
>   entered the URL manually please check your spelling and try again.

Comment: well, you have the `static_folder` defined as `templates/assets` not as `assets`

Comment: @IgnacioVergaraKausel http://127.0.0.1:5000/templates/assets/result.csv doesn't work too

Comment: if `static_folder` defined as `templates/assets`, and you want to get `results.csv` I think you should get `http://127.0.0.1:5000/results/result.csv` (assuming you have a `result.csv` file in `templates/assets` folder on you server)

Answer (score 1):

Might be worth to check what `os.path.join('results', filename).replace('\\','/')` evaluates to.

Have you tried a (little safer) approach using `send_from_directory`?

(Didn't check if it actually works):

```
@app.route('/results/<path:filename>', methods=['GET'])
def serve_static(filename):
    return send_from_directory(os.path.dirname(os.getcwd()), filename)
```